# Find the equation of the line parallel to $2x-y=4$ through point $(0,3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have used the point-slope formula and concluded this:

$$2x-y=4$$

$$-y=-2x$$

$$-y-3=-2(x-0)$$

$$-y-3=-2x+0$$

$$2x-y=3 $$

The answer in the text book says $2x-y=-3.$

Is my answer wrong? and if so how could i improve it?

Comment: Try plugging in $x=0$ into your equation. What do you get for $y$?

Comment: i get y=-3 through that

Comment: Right, and what’s the $y$ value that you should have? Remember what they told you in the problem.

Comment: Yes correct , so we plug in the x and y value at end of the equation?

Comment: As @Crosby indicates you can always check which is right by putting in the values you are given - you should get used to doing this as a check on your workings, at least until you are really confident - and even beyond that it will save you from many a slip and error of signs.

Comment: Your main error was $-y = -1*y$ so when you plug in $y-3$ you should have $-(y-3) = -y + 3$ and not $-y -3$.... but frankly you shouldn't just write down a bunch of stuff without explaining them.  If $2x-y = 4$ is a true statement, then $-y=-2x + 4$ is a true statement and $-y=2x$ is a *FALSE* statemen.  And if $-y = 2x$ is a true statement then $-(y-3) = 2(x-0)$ is not true.  Your mechanics of doing these are correct but your explanation of *what* you are doing is utterly wrong and makes no sense.

Comment: "I have used the point-slope formula"  Could you please state exactly what your text says the "point-slope formula" is.  ... I dont know if you are allowed to just throw the $4$ away... annd in any event you should isolate that *positive* $y$... not the $-y$.  If you had done $y = 2x -4$ rather than $-y = -2x + 4$ (or $-y=-2x$) I don't think you ever would have made your error.

Comment: y-y1=m(x-x1)  the third column

Comment: There’s a much simpler way IMO to approach this problem: all lines parallel to the original one have equations of the form $2x-y=c$. Plug in the coordinates of the point and solve for $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plug $x=0$ into your final equation, you get $y=-3$. This means that you must have made a mistake somewhere: the question demands that the line pass through $(0,3)$, not $(0,-3)$. As Mark Bennet pointed out in the comments, it's a good habit to check your work by plugging in the values you've been given.

Regarding your work, you seem to have misapplied the point-slope formula. If we solve for $y$ in the original equation, we see that

$$y=2x-4,$$

so the parallel line has a slope of $2$. Therefore, the equation you want is

$$\color{blue}{y}-3=\color{blue}{2}(x-0).$$

You wrote

$$\color{red}{-y}-3=\color{red}{-2}(x-0).$$

Can you take it from here?

**Edit:** We have 
$$y-3=2x.$$
From here, to get to your textbook’s answer, we can subtract $y$ from both sides. That would give
$$2x-y=-3.$$
We could also add $3$ to both sides. That would give
$$y=2x+3.$$
Both equations are correct and represent the same line.

Comment: The slope can't be subtracted from both sides?

so we just apply the formula as its +y-y1=+m(x-x1)?

Comment: i picked it up from y−3=2(x−0). and got this

y-3=2x-0

Here what should i do next? move 2x to y or y to 2x? this part is what really confuses me and i make the mistake cause if i move 2x to y i get y-2x=3 and vice versa i get 2x-y=-3

Comment: @Yoda The most logical thing to do would be to isolate $y$. We can do that by adding $3$ to both sides. What does that give you?

Comment: if i isolate it goes as y=2x+3

Comment: @Yoda Great! That’s the correct answer and equivalent to the answer in your textbook. Are you confused as to how to get to your textbook’s answer?

Comment: Yes! the book says 2x-y=-3

Comment: @Yoda Yes. I know. The equation $y=2x+3$ is equivalent to $2x-y=-3$. I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: so its the same thing? both are correct? , EDIT: just tried it and got -3=2x-y

Comment: @Yoda Yes. They both represent the same line. You can rearrange one and get the other.

Comment: Thank you good sir! you have cleared my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful.  And make sure what you say actually *means* something.

You say $2x-y =4$.  That's not true or accurate.

What if $x = 27$ and $y = 39$?  Well, you might answer, then $(27,39)$ are not on the line described by $2x-y=4$.  But I'd counter you didn't *say* that $(x,y)$ was one the first line.  You just said $2x-y = 4$ with no explanation as to where $x,y$ came from.

Then you say $-y = -2x$.  Well, if $2x-y = 4$ then $-y=-2x + 4\ne -2x$.  That's contradictory.  Well, you might answer, this is about $x,y$ on a different line so this is a different $x,y$.

But you didn't say you were talking about different values of $x,y$.

....

Which is not to say you are doing anything wrong, but that you aren't *explaining* what you are doing.

====

Let's start over.

We have an equation for the first line. $2x-y = 4$ and that can be rewritten as $-y =-2x +4$.

In terms of the slope that means $-(\text{any change in }y) = -2(\text{any change in }x)$.  This is true for the first line $2x-y =4$ and for any line parallel to the first line.

This mean for any $(x_1,y_1)$ on a line parallel to the first line that

$-(y-y_1) = -2(x - x_2)$.

And as $(0,3)$ is a point one the second line, we have

$-(y-3) = -2(x-0)$.

**And this is where you made your mistake.  You did $-y-3 = -2(x-0)$ and not $-(y-3)=-2(x0)$**.

So the equation for the line is $-(y-3) =-2(x-0)$

$-y+3 = -2x$

$2x -y = -3$.

====

It'd be easier to do:

Equation of first line.

$2x - y = 4$ or equivalently

$y = 2x -4$.

So the slope of first line is $2$.

So equation of a parallel line is $y = 2x + b$.  As $(0,3)$ is in the second line we know

$3 = 2*0 + b$ so $b = 3$ and equation for second line is $y = 2x +3$

Or equivalently $2x - y = -3$.

=====

if we assume we know that if parallel lines will have the same $x,y$ coefficients, then it'd be even *easier* to do:

Then if line one is $2x-y = 4$ then the equation for a parallel line will be:

$2x -y = c$ for some constant $c$.

As $(0,3)$ is a point on the line with have:

$2*0 - 3 = c$

so $c = -3$ and

$2x-y = -3$ is the equation for the seccond line.

Comment: i wrote it step by step as i attempted it , i usually type out first the original equation in first step , my bad
 2x−y=4 is the original equation